# What is the best way to create global variables in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp

I'd like to create a global variable in CakePHP. If I define something in in my app_controller.php like

```
var $varName
```

I can access

```
$this->varName
```

from any of my controllers, but I cannot get to it from models.

How can I create a global variable accessible from the models?

The value of $varName isn't known until runtime, so I don't think bootstrap.php is an option.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> CakePHP’s new [Configure class](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html#configure-class) can be
>   used to store and retrieve application
>   or runtime specific values. Be
>   careful, this class allows you to
>   store anything in it, then use it in
>   any other part of your code

Comment: This is an old answer, but for anyone wonder why you should "be careful" it's because this class is `a sure temptation to break the MVC pattern CakePHP was designed for. The main goal of Configure class is to keep centralized variables that can be shared between many objects. Remember to try to live by "convention over configuration" and you won't end up breaking the MVC structure we’ve set in place.`

Comment: Is this a good place to put a global variable for Test mode vs Live mode?  I have some routines I want to behave differently if we are testing.

Answer (score 32):

To save global variables use the Configure Class. For example:

> Configure::write('Company.name','Pizza, Inc.');

To read the variable later in any place of your code use:

> Configure::read('Company.name');    //yields: 'Pizza, Inc.'

The recommended file to store global constants is in **app/config/bootstrap.php**

For more information see:
Configure class  -  [Configure Class CakePhp](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html#configure-class).
or Section 3.4.7 on Bootstrapping

Comment: Ax's answer was correct, but I gave this +1 for giving an example too - just what I needed when googling this.

Comment: This is fine but if data is user specific, Session class could be useful

Answer (score 4):

you can declare global variable in app/cofig/core.php

```
Configure::write('variable Name','Variable Value');
```

you can print like that :

```
Configure::read('Variable Name');
```

Answer (score 2):

Global functions and variables for your app can be defined in the app/config/bootstrap.php

for more info see http://book.cakephp.org/view/48/Bootstrapping-CakePHP

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20090313201654/http://book.cakephp.org/view/48/Bootstrapping-CakePHP

Answer (score 1):

You can define constants in bootstrap.php in app/config/ directory. It can be used globally into any controller or view.

Answer (score 0):

You can try define constants with bootstrap.php (cake 3)

> This file is ideal for a number of common bootstrapping tasks:
>
> Defining convenience functions.
>
> Declaring constants.
>
> Defining cache configuration.
>
> Defining logging configuration.
>
> Loading custom inflections.
>
> Loading configuration files.

ref https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/configuration.html#bootstrapping-cakephp

Answer (score -2):

Actually, why are you doing that? The model should have no idea that a controller exists.

If it is a business (model) object, create it as such. If not, the model should not know it.

Comment: Some global variables are pretty standard.  For example, my test server and my production server are located at two very different domains, and I often need to create links to them... even in the models.  So having a global variable for that doesn't really break any design principles.  It actually could potentially save you from breaking design principles.

Comment: There are some simple things that it's not worth the extra database calls/cpu cyles/disk reads to make a model etc, just for the sake of a simple list of values. Design principles are just that - principles. Sometimes a principle doesn't apply to the real world.