# pass data from one controller action to another controller action cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

how do I pass a variable that was set in controller action A, to controller action B without calling controller action B in controller action A? I tried creating a variable in the model, but this only works only within one controller action. If I change the value inside one controller action, the change is not reflected inside another controller action.

Any help please?

Comment: How are actions A and B executed?

Comment: Action A is the add() action, action B is a custom action that needs the id of the user that added the data from action A

Comment: And how is the execution of B triggered? Is it run during the same HTTP request that caused A to be executed?

Comment: You can always store temporary data in the session but that may have unexpected side effects if the user has several tabs/windows open at the same time.

Comment: see this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/639564/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-global-variables-in-cakephp[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/639564/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-global-variables-in-cakephp

Answer (score 0):

Action A will not know anything about action B unless it is called from action A. So how do you propose to run action B when action A is run without calling it? It cannot be done.