# CakePHP Normalization

Tags: php, list, cakephp, relational-database, database-normalization

I am debating over the amount of normalization to use in my tables.

For example, if I have a database table called `players` with columns such as `name, hometown, etc..`.

Other columns are options `bats` (right, left, or switch), or `status` (active, injured) that with be displayed as radio buttons or drop downs.

Currently, our database stores these options in their own tables `bats` and `statuses` and we reference the related table with the fields `bat_id`and `status_id`.

If the `bats` and `statuses` tables are simply storing a list of names and ids and will always have less than 10 values, should I flatten the database and simply store the values directly in the `players` table?

When creating radio inputs for those fields I might have to execute a `group by` query on a large table.  Would it make sense to [store the possible values globally](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4471175/55124) as an array in app/config/bootstrap.php or by using the configure class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my opinion you can really seldom overuse normalization. I'd avoid globals as much as I can.

If your bats and statuses tables will hold "only" configuration or status key data you might put all of them together in a single table, accessible by namespace.

E.g.:

```
  id | namespace | value
---------------------------
   1 | bats      | left
   2 | bats      | right
   3 | bats      | swing
   4 | status    | active
   5 | status    | injured
```

... etc, you get it. Simply have an index on the namespace to help the database - unless there are really only a few lines in there where a decent DB would ignore the index anyway.