# How to define variable in cakephp which is accessible throughout the application?

Tags: cakephp

I want to define a variable in cakephp that can be accessed from anywhere (i.e model,controller,component etc.) without using session. How to achieve this in cakephp, any suggestion?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to create global variables in CakePHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/639564/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-global-variables-in-cakephp)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could define **constants** in `app/Config/bootstrap.php`, but a better solution would be use `Configure::write();`

For example if you want read some variable anywhere, you can set it in `bootstrap.php` file (`app/Config/`) or in Your `AppController.php` (`app/Controllers`) by:

```
Configure::write('variable_name', 'variable_value');
```

and read it anywhere by:

```
Configure::read('variable_name');
```

Comment: I can't use Configure::write(), since this uses session to store its value... What I have done is that I have created global variable in bootstrap.php using global keyword and redeclare this on every function with global keyword... and then accessed its value... and its working...

Comment: Static class Configure not using session, but store data in variable.

Comment: Read: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html#configure-class

Comment: Why is `Configure::write()` "better" than `const` or `define()`?

Answer (score 1):

I create an application-specific configuration file at **app/Config/app.php** that looks like this:

```
<?php
$config = array(
    'App' => array(
        'name' => 'My App Name'
    )
);
```

And then include it in my CakePHP application by including the following line in my **app/Config/bootstrap.php** file:

```
Configure::load('app');
```

This gives me one file in which all of my application-specific configuration settings are, without peppering my codebase with `Configure::write()` calls.