# Making a GET variable available in all methods

Tags: php, cakephp

I have created an application based on cakephp. By using GET (?site=x) I want to make the variable "site" available in all action methods. But if I call any URL with the get param ?site=x it disappears when I call any other URL. By using caches I thought that I could save ?site=x when any URL is called for the first time. When other URLs in the application are called it can be easily retrieved from cache and can be added to the called URL.

I want to know if it is a good approach or do you think there are other better solutions for this problem.

Comment: if it's always going to be present in the url, then why bother having it in the url at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am confused what you want to do , but if you want to define a variable that will present for all functions,you can do it via several way :-

1.Either define it in App controller as public variable. It will present to all other controllers.

2.Either define it in `beforeFilter()` function of a particular controller. But that variable will present for all methods of that particular controller.

3.Either define it like global variable and for that check this:- [What is the best way to create global variables in CakePHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639564/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-global-variables-in-cakephp)

4.You can use `SESSION` too.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes but the content of the variable should be changed by the user. Therefore I am using GET. If someone calls any url ?site=123 , it should be added to all other URLs too.

Comment: isn't it conflicting? suppose i am the user and i open two tabs on same system same browser  and give different values and then what happen?

Comment: according to the content of the variable different SQL statements are executed. the last called ?site=x should be the current variable.

Comment: then assign it  in `SESSION` in `beforefilter()` function of all controllers